# Azure DevOps pipeline task to remove key in AppService Settings

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-appservice

I use Azure App Service Settings [task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureAppServiceSettingsV1/README.md) to update or add AppService settings. However now I need to delete a key and can't figure out how to do it.. The problem is there might remain keys that have been set during some testing period.

Can it be done with this task or is there another task? I don't want to do it in the portal (in fact I don't have access, I only have set up the service principal in the pipeline, so I need to do it in the pipeline).

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureAppServiceSettingsV1/README.md), I try to add two keys, then delete them via [Azure CLI](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureCLIV1/Readme.md) task, it works. We could add the task `Azure CLI` in the pipeline definition to delete appsettings, like:

```
az webapp config appsettings delete --name {App Service name} --resource-group {Resource group name} --setting-names {key names}
```

[image]

Comment: I liked it and it seems to be perfect (also for other things to be done) but it does not work for me. The error is `##[error]Script failed with error: ERROR: The subscription of '<guid>' doesn't exist in cloud 'AzureCloud'.` The ARM connections is set to Service Connection that works otherwise, the subscription id is taken from it and it is correct and the same value I can see in the portal. It is in Azure Cloud environment. So everything seems to be set correctly.

Comment: Tried to downgrade the Azure CLI task to 1.* and it works. It does not work with 2.0 version only.